# Adapting coordinates in cartopy depending on the projection of a plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, cartopy

In the  following example, I am losing my point (i.e., I don't understand the change in coordinates) if I am using the `ccrs.Mercator()` projection instead of the `ccrs.PlateCarree()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

mypt = (6, 56)

ax0 = plt.subplot(221, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) # OK
ax1 = plt.subplot(222, projection=ccrs.Mercator())    # NOT OK
ax2 = plt.subplot(224, projection=ccrs.Mercator())    # NOT OK

def plotpt(ax, extent=(-15,15,46,62)):
    ax.plot(mypt[0], mypt[1], 'r*', ms=20)
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plotpt(ax0)
plotpt(ax1)
plotpt(ax2, extent=(-89,89,-89,89))

plt.show()
```

[image]

It looks like the coordinates of my point go from (6,56) to (0,0)
What am I missing? 
Why is the behaviour correct with `ccrs.PlateCarree()` and not with `ccrs.Mercator()`? Should I add any transform somewhere?

---

[*EDIT with the solution*]

My initial confusion came from the fact that `projection` applies to the plot, while `transform` applies to the data, meaning they should be set different when they do not share the same system - my first attempts with `transform` where wrong as in `ax1` below, `ax1bis` is the solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

mypt = (6, 56)

ax0 = plt.subplot(221, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1 = plt.subplot(222, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax1bis = plt.subplot(223, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax2 = plt.subplot(224, projection=ccrs.Mercator())

def plotpt(ax, extent=(-15,15,46,62), **kwargs):
    ax.plot(mypt[0], mypt[1], 'r*', ms=20, **kwargs)
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

plotpt(ax0) # correct because projection and data share the same system
plotpt(ax1, transform=ccrs.Mercator()) # WRONG
plotpt(ax1bis, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) # Correct, projection and transform are different!
plotpt(ax2, extent=(-89,89,-89,89), transform=ccrs.Mercator()) # WRONG

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should add the `transform` keyword to the `plot` call. You should also specify the coordinate system you want to set the extents in:

```
def plotpt(ax, extent=(-15,15,46,62)):
    ax.plot(mypt[0], mypt[1], 'r*', ms=20, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
```

A basic guide on transforms and projections is now available in the cartopy documentation http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html. To avoid surprises, you should *always* specify a transform when plotting data on a map.

Comment: Thanks - OK actually the key point here is that `projection` determines the projection of the plot, while `transform` determines the system of the data, meaning that a plot with `projection=ccrs.Mercator()` should still be used with `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` if the data are in lon-lat coordinates. Your example is not solving my initial problem since it addresses the case with `ccrs.PlateCarree()`, which remains incidently correct because this is the system of the data. I would suggest to adapt the answer for the more tricky ´ccrs.Mercator()´ case...